# How to use response received through ajax in view in laravel and not to write HTML in controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to convert data from ajax response in HTML mostly I read articles everyone does code HTML in controller where i am confused that we should not write any kind of HTML in controller. i wrote the HTML in controller but not satisfied with this kind of programming. How can I get the response and what formate so i can code that response in HTML either received in JSON or anything else.
In view m showing the list of manufactures. Any better way clean way to not to write HTML in controller

View

```
    <div class="pl-md-4 pl-2">
        {{count($leedManufacturers)}}
        <label class=" my-checkbox gry2">Show All Manufacturers
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        @if(count($leedManufacturers) > 0 )

        @foreach($leedManufacturers as $leedsManufacturer)
        {{-- @foreach($leedManufacturers as $leedsManufacturer)  --}}
            <div class="post" id="post{{$leedsManufacturer['id']}}">
                <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{str_limit($leedsManufacturer['name'], 300)}}
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            {{-- for load more script --}}
        {{-- <input type="hidden" id="row" value="0"> --}}

        {{-- <input type="hidden" id="all" value="{{$total_manufacturers}}"> --}}
        @endforeach

        @endif

        <button class="load-more" id="load" class="f-14 bold">See All</button>

        <input type="hidden" id="row" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" id="all" value="{{count($leedManufacturers)}}">


    </div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
            $(document).ready(function(){

            // Load more data
            $('.load-more').click(function(){
                var row = Number($('#row').val());
                var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
                var rowperpage = 3;
                // row = row + rowperpage;
                row = row + 3;

                if(row <= allcount){
                    $("#row").val(row);

                    $.ajax({
                    // url: "{{ route('ajax') }}",
                    url: "{{ url('ajax') }}",
                    type: 'post',

                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    data: {row:row},

                    // error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //     alert('hi');
                    // }

                    success: function(response){

                    // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                        $(".post").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");

                        var rowno = row + 3;

                        // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                        if(rowno > allcount){

                            // Change the text and background
                            $('.load-more').text("show less");
                            $('.load-more').css("background","darkorchid");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Load more");
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                    }
 });

                }else{
            $('.load-more').text("Loading...");

            // Setting little delay while removing contents
            setTimeout(function() {

                // When row is greater than allcount then remove all class='post' element after 3 element
                $('.post:nth-child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");

                // Reset the value of row
                $("#row").val(0);

                // Change the text and background
                $('.load-more').text("Load more");
                $('.load-more').css("background","#15a9ce");

            }, 2000);
        }
            });

            });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function ajax(Request $request){ 

    $data['products'] = Product::select('products.id', 'products.name', 'products.banner')->get();

    $html = '';

    foreach ($data['products'] as $product){

        $html .= '<div class="post" id="">';
        $html .= '<label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">'.$product->name.'';
        $html .= '<input type="checkbox">';
        $html .= '<span class="checkmark"></span>';
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '</div>';  
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: instead of `echo $html` try to use `return $html`

Comment: does it make any difference. am asking how can i remove HTML code form Controller and make some mechanism that write HTML code in HTML file only

Comment: I'm voting to close this as _too broad_. Also note that it has been posted [on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220220/120114)

Comment: did you get its solution

Comment: yes i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Inside controller use

```
public function ajax(Request $request){ 
    $products = Product::select('products.id', 'products.name', 'products.banner')->get();
    return view('ajax.product', compact('products'));
}
```

inside view create a ajax view in my case views/ajax/product.blade.php
and use this code

```
@foreach ($products as $product){
    <div class="post" id="">
    <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{ $product->name }}
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    </div>  
@endforech
```

Comment: view is already loaded in another method() can't load another view i have to return something like json or anything else that can e used without loading the new view

Answer (score 0):

You can return the dedicated view in your ajax and inject it in your already loaded view.

Create a view for example ajax.blade.php

```
<div>
@foreach ($products as $product){
    <div class="post" id="">
        <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{ $product->name }}
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>  
@endforech
</div>
```

And in your controller you can check for ajax request and return the render, this will return a raw html that you can inject in your html through ajax.

```
return view('views.ajax')->with('products', $products)->render();
```

And in you script then you can simply

```
success: fucntion(response){
  document.querySelector('#id').innerHTML = response
}
```